# Content bumping other content down

Tags: html, css

When I add content to my code, it bumps my page and footers down.I can't figure out why! When I add the smallest bit of content, it bumps a lot of my page elements down and all over the place. Any help would be appreciated. Not sure if I am posting this code correctly, please let me know if I need to do anything.

```css
/* null margins and padding to give good cross-browser baseline */
html,body,address,blockquote,div,
form,fieldset,caption,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,
hr,ul,li,ol,ul,
table,tr,td,th,p,img{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

img, fieldset {
 border:none;
}

body {
 padding-top:2em;
 font:normal 100%/150% "segoe ui",helvetica,sans-serif;
 background-image: url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/9tzv4n.jpg);
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
    background-repeat: repeat;
 color:#FFF;
}

p {
 margin-top:20px;
}




#bottom {
 
    background-image: url("http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah69/danalavelle3/Sawtooth_zps67oxpl7p.png");
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px;
    position: absolute;
  
}



#page {
  background:url('http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah69/danalavelle3/Page_zpscom5uhou.png');
  width:100%;
  min-height:1000px;
  margin-top:-55px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  position:absolute;
 
}



h1 {

 position:relative;
 z-index: 7;
 font:bold 40px/42px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
 background:url(http://www.cutcodedown.com/for_others/barrelPony/sandmannFarm/images/h1BottomStripe.png) bottom left repeat-x;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:20px;
 background-image: url(http://www.cutcodedown.com/for_others/barrelPony/sandmannFarm/images/h1BottomStripe.png), url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/33dfi86.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
    background-position: bottom left, bottom left;
 
}


h1 a {
 position:relative;
 zoom:1; /* trip haslayout, fix legacy IE bugs */
 display:block;
 padding:30px 0;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:
  0 0 2px #000,
  2px 2px 3px #754;
}

h1 span {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 width:402px;
 height:160px;
 margin:-80px 0 0 -201px;
 text-indent:-999em;
 background:url(http://www.cutcodedown.com/for_others/barrelPony/sandmannFarm/images/h1Logo.png);
}



h1 small {
 display:block;
 font:bold 16px/18px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;

}



#mainMenuCheck {
 /* display none breaks this in some browsers, so just slide it out of view */
 position:absolute;
 left:-999em;
}

#mainMenu {
 position:relative; /* depth sort over h1 */
 background:#754 url(images/dots.png) top left;
 padding:0.75em 0 0.75em 0.75em;
 /* left margin adjusts for uneven menu width, change as needed */
 text-align:center;
}

#mainMenu li {
 list-style:none;
 display:inline;
}

#mainMenu ul:before,
#mainMenu ul:after,
#mainMenu:after,
#mainMenu a {
 text-shadow:
  0 0 2px #000,
  2px 2px 2px #000,
  2px 2px 3px #000;
}

#mainMenu a {
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#F0E8E0;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s, text-shadow 0.3s;
 transition:color 0.3s, text-shadow 0.3s;
}

#mainMenu a.current {
 color:#87C6BC;
}

#mainMenu a:active,
#mainMenu a:focus,
#mainMenu a:hover {
 color:#87C6BC;
}

#mainMenu a:after {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:0 0.1em 0 0.5em;
 color:#FFF;
}

#mainMenu .lastInSet a:after {
 display:none;
}

#mainMenu .setBreak {
 padding-right:8em;
}

#mainMenu a:after,
#mainMenu:after,
#mainMenu ul:before,
#mainMenu ul:after {
 content:"\2605";
 font-family:"arial unicode ms","dejavu sans",lastresort,sans-serif;
}

#mainMenu:after,
#mainMenu ul:before,
#mainMenu ul:after {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 width:3em;
 bottom:0.65em;
}

#mainMenu:after {
 bottom:0.2em;
 font-size:150%;
 margin-left:-1.5em;
}

#mainMenu ul:before {
 margin-left:-3em;
}

@media (min-width:1px) { /* sneaky trick to target just CSS3 browsers */
/*
 h1 span {
  background:url(images/h1Logo2x.png);
  background-size:cover;
 }
 uncomment for 2x resolution logo support
*/
}

@media (max-width:50em) {
 #mainMenu {
  padding:1em 0 0.5em;
 }
 #mainMenu ul {
  max-width:25em;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
 #mainMenu .setBreak {
  padding-right:0;
 }
 /*
  restyle menu to 'mobile friendly' finger-sized targets
 */
 #mainMenu:after,
 #mainMenu a:after,
 #mainMenu ul:before,
 #mainMenu ul:after {
  
 }
 #mainMenu a {
  padding:0.5em 1em;
  margin:0 0.15em 0.5em;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius:1em;
  border-radius:1em;
 }
}

@media (max-width:26em) {
 body {
  padding-top:0;
 }
 h1 {
  text-align:left;
  font:bold 150%/120% arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  
 }
 h1 a {
  padding:0.25em 3em 0.25em 0.25em;
  
 }
 h1 small {
  font:bold 80%/120% "segoe ui",arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  
 }
 h1 span,
 #mainMenu:before {
  display:none;
 }
 #mainMenuCheck + label {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:99;
  right:0.25em;
  top:0.3em;
  width:3em;
  padding:0.5em 0;
  background:#488;
  border:0.25em solid #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius:0.75em;
  border-radius:0.75em;
  display:none;
 }
 #mainMenuCheck + label:hover {
  background:#6BB;
  display: none;
 }
 #mainMenuCheck + label:before,
 #mainMenuCheck + label:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:0.5em;
  margin:0 0.5em;
  border:solid #FFF;
  border-width:0.25em 0;


 }
 #mainMenuCheck + label:after {
  border-width:0 0 0.25em;
  
 }
 #mainMenu {
  display:none;
  padding:0.5em 0.5em 0;
 }
 #mainMenuCheck:checked ~ #mainMenu {
  display:block;

 
 }
}


/**MENU**/

@media (min-width:52em) {

 .header {
  display: none;
 }

 .menu {
  display: none;
 }


}

@media (max-width:52em) {

 body {
   z-index: 100; 
   margin:;
   font-family: font:bold 16px/18px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
   

 }

 a {
   color: #F8F4E6;
   text-shadow:
  0 0 5px #000,
  5px 5px 5px #754;
 }

 .menu a:before,
 .menu ul:before,
 .menu ul:before {
  content:"\2605";

 }


 /* header */

 .header {
   background-color:#6A4E39;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 3;


 }

 .header ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-image:none;

 }

 .header li a {
   display: block;
   padding: 20px 20px;
   border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .header li a:hover,
 .header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color:#4EB4AC;
   
 }

 .header .logo {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   font-size: 15px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 /* menu */

 .header .menu {
   clear: both;
   max-height: 0;
   transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
 }

 /* menu icon */

 .header .menu-icon {
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
   padding: 28px 20px;
   position: relative;
   user-select: none;
 }

 .header .menu-icon .navicon {
   background: #F8F4E6;
   display: block;
   height: 2px;
   position: relative;
   transition: background .2s ease-out;
   width: 18px;
 }

 .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
 .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
   background: #F8F4E6;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   transition: all .2s ease-out;
   width: 100%;
 }

 .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
   top: 5px;
 }

 .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
   top: -5px;
 }

 /* menu btn */

 .header .menu-btn {
   display: none;
 }

 .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
   max-height: none;
 }

 .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
   background: transparent;
 }

 .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }

 .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
   transform: rotate(45deg);
 }

 .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
 .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
   top: 0;
 }
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 52em) {
  .header li {
  float: left;
 
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 52em) {
  #mainMenu {
   display: none;
   justify-content: center;
  }


/* section */

.section {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.section a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.section a img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.section a span {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

.section-split a span {
  display: none;
}

.section-split a:hover span {
  display: block;
}


/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .section-split a {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen,projection,tv">
<title>Sandmann Farm</title>

</head>


<body>



<h1>
 <a href="/">
  Sandmann Farm
  <span>-</span>
  <small>EST. 1975</small>
 </a>
</h1>

 
<!--Menu -->

<input type="checkbox" id="mainMenuCheck">
<label for="mainMenuCheck"></label>

<div id="mainMenu">
 <ul>

  <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
  <li class="lastInSet setBreak"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
  
  <li><a href="#">Success Stories</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
  <li class="lastInSet"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

 </ul>

<!-- #mainMenu --></div>


<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<header class="header">
  <a href="/" class="logo">Navigation</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">     Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">     About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">     What We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">     Success Stories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">     Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">     Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">     Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

 
<!-- Page -->
  
  <div id="page"></div>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

<!--Header -->

 <div id="sawtoothb"></div>

 <div style="height: 100px; background-image:url('http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah69/danalavelle3/Sawtooth_zps67oxpl7p.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; margin-top: -110px;">
 </div>

<!--Footer -->

 <div id="footer"></div>
 <div id="bottom"></div>

 <div></div>
 <div style="height: 100px; background-image:url('http://oi66.tinypic.com/2ufrt77.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; margin-top: -40px;margin-bottom:25px;">
 </div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Hi BarrelPony, welcome to Stack!  Your question has a LOT of code to parse through.  Have you tried reducing it to a smaller problem?  We don't work quite like other forums here, and tend to focus on issues that have already been reduced down to their root problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being bumped down, you `#page` just has a huge `min-height`. Setting `min-height` will mean that whatever you define, in your case `min-height:1000px` that will be the **mininum** height of that element, it will never be smaller than 1000px, no matter what.

You can find this declaration here:

```
#page {
     background:url('http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah69/danalavelle3/Page_zpscom5uhou.png');
     width:100%;
     min-height:1000px;
     margin-top:-55px;
     margin-bottom:100px;
     position:absolute;
 }
```

Just remove the `min-height:1000px`, I added this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h1qaLkj/)** to show you the result as well.

Comment: That didn't change anything on my end . . .

Comment: @BarrelPony What exactly is happening on your end? I can put text in fine and nothing gets bumped down? Could you please elaborate? What div are you putting text into, which div is getting bumped? Etc..